# Unexplainable SQL behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a simple SQL query, with a handful of joined queries.

In my select I have a function shaping the date to a string format as below

```
 LEFT(REPLACE(ADM_DT,'-',''),8)+REPLACE(ADM_TM,':','')+'00'
```

The script I am running should return 84 rows currently, but when executing the above in the select, it continuosly returns a different volume of rows every execution? there are no changes to the underlying tables between executions.

The strange thing is that whe I swith this back to a standard date conversion, the rows total 84

```
 CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ADM_DT)+' '+ADM_TM)
```

Can anyone explain why SQL is behaving this way, I have not seen this before?

Full script below:

```
 SELECT
  [Visit ID] = a050.HSP_NO
  ,[Current Site] = currwd.HOSP
  ,[Current Specialty]  = curr.SPEC 
  ,[Current Ward] = currwd.WARD
  ,[Current Ward Name] = REPLACE(currwd.CURRDESC,'"','')
  ,[Current Consultant] = curr.PROF
  ,[Admission Date] = LEFT(REPLACE(ADM_DT,'-',''),8)+REPLACE(ADM_TM,':','')+'00' 
  ,[Active] = '1'
  ,[PAS ID] = [crn].[crn]
  ,[Patient Class] = 'IP'
  ,NHS.[nhsno]
  ,CHI.CHI
  ,CASE WHEN OSV.X_CN IS NOT NULL THEN 'OSV' ELSE '' END OSV
  ,CASE WHEN NHS.[nhsno] LIKE '7%' THEN '7 NHSNO' ELSE '' END [PROBLEM NHS NO]
  ,DATEDIFF(D,PATS.DATE_OF_BIRTH,CONVERT(DATE,ADM_DT)) /365 [AGE ON ADMISSION]

 FROM PCSSSA..SILVER.APK050_HPROVSPELL a050 WITH (NOLOCK)

-- Current Admission details
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT X_CN, CEP_NO, HSP_NO, SPEC, PROF --MSPEC 
    FROM PCSSSA..SILVER.APK051_CONEPIS epi WITH (NOLOCK)
    -- Main Specialty Map
    LEFT JOIN PCSSSA..SILVER.ENV050_DISCIPDETS en050 WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON epi.SPEC = en050.OBJ_DISC 
    AND en050.OBJ_TYPE='SP' 
    AND en050.DATE_TO IS NULL 
    )curr
ON curr.X_CN = a050.X_CN 
AND a050.HSP_NO = curr.HSP_NO
AND curr.CEP_NO = (SELECT TOP 1 a051.CEP_NO
                    FROM PCSSSA..SILVER.APK051_CONEPIS a051 WITH (NOLOCK)
                    Where a051.X_CN = a050.X_CN AND a050.HSP_NO = a051.HSP_NO
                    Order By CEP_NO DESC)

-- Current Ward Detail
JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X_CN, CEP_NO ORDER BY WS_NO DESC) AS WR 
      FROM PCSSSA..SILVER.APK052_WARDSTAY wdstay WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                        CURRWARD = OBJ_LOC, 
                        CURRDESC = OBJ_DESC 
                    FROM [PCSSSA]..[SILVER].[ENV030_LOCDETS] WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE OBJ_TYPE = 'WARD'
                    AND DATE_TO IS NULL
                    )wdname
        ON wdstay.WARD = wdname.CURRWARD
      ) currwd 
ON curr.X_CN = currwd.X_CN 
AND curr.CEP_NO = currwd.CEP_NO 
AND currwd.WR=1

--- Admitting details
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT X_CN, CEP_NO, HSP_NO, PROF, SPEC --MSPEC  
    FROM PCSSSA..SILVER.APK051_CONEPIS epi WITH (NOLOCK)
    -- Main Specialty Map
    LEFT JOIN PCSSSA..SILVER.ENV050_DISCIPDETS en050 WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON epi.SPEC = en050.OBJ_DISC 
    AND en050.OBJ_TYPE='SP' 
    AND en050.DATE_TO IS NULL 
    )adm
ON adm.X_CN = a050.X_CN AND a050.HSP_NO = adm.HSP_NO
AND adm.CEP_NO = (SELECT TOP 1 a051.CEP_NO
                    FROM PCSSSA..SILVER.APK051_CONEPIS a051 WITH (NOLOCK)
                    Where a051.X_CN = a050.X_CN AND a050.HSP_NO = a051.HSP_NO
                    Order By CEP_NO)

-- Admitting Ward Detail
JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X_CN,CEP_NO ORDER BY WS_NO) AS WR FROM PCSSSA..SILVER.APK052_WARDSTAY WITH (NOLOCK)) admwd 
ON adm.X_CN = admwd.X_CN 
AND adm.CEP_NO = admwd.CEP_NO 
AND admwd.WR=1

-- Patient Detail
LEFT JOIN             
    (SELECT       
        [id].[RM_PATIENT_NO],
        [id].[NUM_ID_TYPE] + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,[NUMBER_ID]) [crn]
    FROM [PCSSSA]..[SILVER].[NUMBER_IDS] [id]  WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE [id].[NUM_ID_TYPE] IN ('0', '1', 'W')
)[crn]
ON a050.[X_CN] = [crn].[RM_PATIENT_NO]

-- NHS NUMBERS
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT     
        [id].[RM_PATIENT_NO],
        [id].[NUMBER_ID] [nhsno]
    FROM [PCSSSA]..[SILVER].[NUMBER_IDS] [id]  WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE [id].[NUM_ID_TYPE] = ('NHS')
    )NHS
ON NHS.RM_PATIENT_NO = a050.X_CN

-- CHI NUMBER
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT       
        [id].[RM_PATIENT_NO],
        [id].[NUMBER_ID] [CHI]
    FROM [PCSSSA]..[SILVER].[NUMBER_IDS] [id]  WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE [id].[NUM_ID_TYPE] IN ('CHI')
    )CHI
ON CHI.RM_PATIENT_NO = a050.X_CN

-- OVERSEES STATUS
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT X_CN, [STATUS], SDATE, EDATE FROM PCSSSA..SILVER.CRS037_OSV_STATUS WITH (NOLOCK)
    )OSV
ON OSV.X_CN = a050.X_CN
AND CONVERT(DATE,ADM_DT) >= OSV.SDATE 
AND (OSV.SDATE IS NULL 
OR CONVERT(DATE,ADM_DT) <= OSV.EDATE)

-- DEMOGRAPHICS
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT RM_PATIENT_NO, DATE_OF_BIRTH FROM PCSSSA..[SILVER].[PATIENTS] WITH (NOLOCK)
    )PATS
ON PATS.RM_PATIENT_NO = a050.X_CN

-- CURRENTLY ADMITTED ONLY
WHERE DIS_DT IS NULL
-- WITHOUT NHS NUMBER
AND (nhsno IS NULL
-- OR BRING IN ANY 7 NHS NUMBERS FOR CORRECTION
OR NHS.[nhsno] LIKE '7%'
-- ALSO INCLUDE OVERSEES
OR OSV.X_CN IS NOT NULL)
```

What is even stranger, is that if you wrap this in a subquery and coun(*) on the outer then it totals 84 as expected, very strange!

Comment: What about the results changes? The row count? The content?

Comment: If you replace your entire select with SELECT 1 FROM .... What happens?

Comment: No volume changes, between executions